# How do I delete a specific item instead of the last item in my list using onclick

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am creating a program that contains items for a shopping list and then the user can add items to the list. I want the user to able to delete items from the shopping list by simply clicking on the item. When I click on the item, the last item gets deleted no matter which item I click on. I just want to find out why only the last item in my array is getting deleted instead of the item that I am selecting.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Shopping List</title>

    <!-- Link Google Font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- External CSS link-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Shopping List</h2>

        <div class="header">
            <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Item">
            <span onclick="updateList(myArray)" id="addBtn"><button>Add Item</button></span>
        </div>
        <span value="\uOOD7" class="close" onclick="deleteItem(myArray)">
        <ul id="itemList">
            

            
        </ul>
    </span>
    </div>

    <script src="mainForTask2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>



Javascript

    //This is a javascript program which added the items in my array to an unordered list
    let myArray = ["Sugar", "Milk", "Bread", "Apples"];
    let list1 = document.querySelector("#itemList");

    //This function pushed my array items to create the list
    arrayList = (arr) => {
    let items = arr.forEach(item => {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = item;
    list1.appendChild(li)
    });
    }

    arrayList(myArray)


    //This function changed the background color of two of the list items to show that they are sold
    const idSelector = () => {
    let idElement = document.getElementsByTagName("li")
    idElement[0].style.color = "red"
    idElement[3].style.color = "red"
    console.log(idElement.value)
    }

    idSelector()

    //This function uses the user input from the form to add items to the list
    updateList = (arr) => {
    let blue = document.getElementById("input").value;

    if (blue === "") {
    alert("Please enter a value if you wish to add something to your 
    list.")
    } else {
    arr.push(blue);
    list1.innerHTML = '';
    arrayList(myArray)
    idSelector()
    }

    }

    //This function is meant to delete the specified item chosen by the user from the shopping list and the array
    deleteItem = (arr) => {
    let red = document.getElementById("close");
    const index = arr.indexOf(red);
    const x = arr.splice(index, 1)
    console.log(arr)
    console.log(x)
    list1.innerHTML = '';
    arrayList(myArray)
    idSelector()
    }
```

Comment: Please post full code that reproduces your issue right here so we can best assist you.  This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Be sure to include the "list" with items and the code you tried.

Comment: Add a ```data-id='my-id'``` attr to each item and then when you click the delete button select the element using that id and remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here first we need to find the clicked element than find its index and than remove the particular element from the array.

```js
let myArray = ["Sugar", "Milk", "Bread", "Apples"];
let list1 = document.querySelector("#itemList");

//This function pushed my array items to create the list
arrayList = (arr) => {
  let items = arr.forEach(item => {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = item;
    list1.appendChild(li)
  });
}

arrayList(myArray)


//This function changed the background color of two of the list items to show that they are sold
const idSelector = () => {
  let idElement = document.getElementsByTagName("li")
  idElement[0].style.color = "red"
  idElement[3].style.color = "red"
}

idSelector()

//This function uses the user input from the form to add items to the list
updateList = (arr) => {
  let blue = document.getElementById("input").value;

  if (blue === "") {
    alert("Please enter a value if you wish to add something to your list.")
  } else {
    arr.push(blue);
    list1.innerHTML = '';
    arrayList(myArray)
    idSelector()
  }

}

//This function is meant to delete the specified item chosen by the user from the shopping list and the array
deleteItem = (event) => {
  let clk = event.target.innerHTML;
  //console.log(clk);
  let index = myArray.indexOf(clk);
  if (index > -1) 
  {
    myArray.splice(index, 1);
  }
  list1.innerHTML = '';
  arrayList(myArray)
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Shopping List</h2>

        <div class="header">
            <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Item">
            <span onclick="updateList(myArray)" id="addBtn"><button>Add Item</button></span>
        </div>
        <span value="\uOOD7" class="close" onclick="deleteItem(event)">
        <ul id="itemList">
            

            
        </ul>
    </span>
    </div>

    <script src="mainForTask2.js"></script>
</body>
```